# Producer - Consumer and database queue

Tags: multithreading, architecture, thread-safety, producer-consumer, database-locking

I have a producer consumer mechanism, **I am forced to store produced items** in database, this is a requirement.  Also I have several producers and several consumers, producers and consumer threads will access records in several database tables; ProcessID column will determine which thread is accessing what record.

Threads will be working through a windows service.

ProcessID is created for three reasons.

- 1- If a thread terminated un-gracefully, the processID will be used to avoid re-starting processing.
- 2- Threads are synchronized through database Locking and hopefully I will got only Row locks, and probably I will have few blocked threads for short time, because every thread will access few records marked with ProcessID.
- 3- I wanted to keep track which thread on which time did what, because I am logging errors into database.  Note that consumers will send items to a Web Service.

If I used In-Memory array as a queue, I doubt that it will enhance performance, it is having the following drawbacks:-

- When a consumer de-queue an item, it will have to update its record in database anyway with its processID.
- The producer will insert item into database, and get its ID using Output stp parameter, then it will put the item in the queue with its ID avoiding re-read it from database, the is the only benefit from the in-Memory queue, avoiding re-read an item from database.
  Note that once a record is inserted in DB, nothing will update it except a consumer.
- Another problem is that, I assume that an operator can stop consuming a certain item by deleting it from database, If I used in memory queue, I will lose this future.
- The Queue class will have to lock on private object, Accessing queue methods should be synchronized.  I feel that I am duplicating the probability that a thread will be starved.  and I feel that I am duplicating the time in which a thread will be blocked waiting.

**Two Questions**

1- Do I miss something in this design?  Do you think it will work?

2- Is it a good idea to not use In-Memory queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I would still make a central in-memory queue as a service which would also take care of correct process retrieval strategy, and updating product rows with statuses. I don't think it's a huge development overhead.

You clearly stated by yourself that there will be situations when threads will be blocked for a short term. Such a queue would pay off if you may need to increase number of threads.

As for this, you can double check before handing over to consumer:

> Another problem is that, I assume that an operator can stop consuming
>   a certain item by deleting it from database, If I used in memory
>   queue, I will lose this future.

And, of course, it's a much clearer design.. you'll follow single responsibility principle, when producers and consumers will take care of only producing and consuming items.

As for:

> 1- Do I miss something in this design? Do you think it will work?

.. I don't see reasons it shouldn't be working. So you have to make a final decision based on the whole picture.